# Testar método de um controller do AngularJs com promise utilizando Karma, Mocha, Chai, Sinon

Tags: angularjs, bdd

Não estou conseguindo testar o código que é executado no *then* do *promise*

Tenho o seguinte controller:

```
class Product extends Controller
  constructor: ($scope, productService) ->
    $scope.product = productService.new()
    $scope.products = []

    $scope.create = ->
      productService.create($scope.product).$promise.then (res) ->
        $scope.products.unshift(res)
        $scope.product = productService.new()
```

E a seguinte classe de teste:

```
describe 'productsController', ->
  q = scope = controller = productService = productServiceMock = undefined

beforeEach module('e-city')

beforeEach ->
  productServiceMock =
    new: -> a: 'a'
    create: (p)->
      qq = q.defer()
      qq.resolve(p)
      $promise: qq.promise
  module ($provide) ->
    $provide.value 'productService', productServiceMock
    null

beforeEach ->
  inject (_productService_, $controller, $rootScope, $q) ->
    q = $q
    productService = _productService_
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    controller = $controller 'productController', $scope: scope

describe 'should test the create method', ->
  it 'should set a new object on $scope.product',  ->
    spy = sinon.spy productService, 'create'
    scope.create()
    spy.should.have.been.called
```

No meu teste eu criei um *Mock* para o *productService* para executar os testes sem incomodar o banco. A questão de *Mock* está funcionando corretamente, só não consigo testar se **productService.new()** está sendo chamado quando o *promise* do **productService.create($scope.product)** é resolvido. O que poderia ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este problema relatado acima em específico o código abaixo já resolve o problema.

```
describe 'create', ->
  it 'should call "new"', inject ($timeout)->
    spy = sinon.spy productService, 'new'
    scope.create()
    $timeout.flush()
    spy.should.have.been.called
    productService.new.restore()
```

> **Obs:** Para otimizar os testes e facilitar a criação dos mocks é recomendado utilizar o **[$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)** do **AngularJs**.